# element RelativeLayout must be declared

Tags: android, xml

I'm getting the error "element `RelativeLayout` must be declared" and I don't know the reason for its occurrence. How do I get rid of this error, please post suggestions or code snippets. This is my `drawer_list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@id/drawer_list_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_900"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_900"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try clean build or restart eclipse and check your connection with android SDK tools

Comment: Try to change the id of your RelativeLayout to: android:id="@+id/drawer_list_item"

Comment: Is the file in `res/layout` folder?

Comment: @programmer23 not working bro

Comment: @Natix yes it is in res/layout

Answer (score 60):

I had faced same error because I add added `Layout resource  file` inside `drawable` folder instead of `layout` folder

> make sure to put `layout files` inside `layout directory`

Comment: Sometimes simpler things make me feel so stupid... Thanks!